# fork and execve to inherit unprivileged parent process' capabilities

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

In Linux system, an unprivileged user launches a program. The process created has the capabilities `CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN` with mode as `effective,permitted,inheritable`.
This process then creates a child process by calling `fork` and  `execv` to invoke another program *udhcpc*, but the child process does not inherit the capabilities `CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN` as expected. Even though before setting the capabilities I have called `prctl(PR_SET_KEEPCAPS, 1)`.

Any suggestion on what to do to inherit unprivileged parent process' capabilities upon `fork` followed by `execve`?

Comment: it seems to be impossible at the moment to preserve capabilities after execve, without setting file capabilities. See [\[RFC\] Capabilities still can't be inherited by normal programs](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1641892)

Comment: Fork can pass them, exec can not (except with ambient). Exec can pass inherited, but the file that is execed also needs this inherited set.

Answer (score 14):

On `execve()`, the file capability sets of the file being executed (in this case, `udhcpc`) are inspected and combined with the thread's capability sets.  In particular, the file's `Inheritable` set is `AND`-ed with the thread's `Inheritable` set to determine the new `Permitted` set, and the file's `Effective` bit must be set in order for the new `Effective` set to be copied from the `Permitted` set.

This implies that in your case you must use `setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=ei /path/to/udhcpc` to obtain the effect you want (in addition to setting the capabilities in the parent process - the `prctl()` is not necessary).

Comment: Hi, Thaks for your valuable answer. I am using the kernel 2.6.18-7.1. I am not able to find the command setcap to provide the capability for an executable. I think it is available in latest kernel. Is there any alternate way to do it in the kernel 2.6.18-7.1.  Thank Eswar

Comment: @user736403: Sorry, I'm not sure what the situation was in those older kernels.

Answer (score 2):

According to "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk (No Starch Press, 2010):

> Since kernel 2.6.24, it is possible to attach capabilities to a file.
>   Various other features were added in kernels 2.6.25 and 2.6.26 in
>   order to complete the capabilities implementation.

The tools  `sucap` and `execcap` are what you should look up.  However they are, if I recall limited to restricting, not granting capabilities.  Look at :

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5737

and

http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0503.1/2540.html

Answer (score 2):

Extracted from the manual, There have been some changes. According to it `fork` does not change capabilities. And now there is an ambient set, it seems that this is for what you are trying to do.

```
   Ambient (since Linux 4.3):
          This is a set of capabilities that are preserved across an execve(2) of a program that is not privileged.  The ambient capability set obeys the invariant that no capability can ever
          be ambient if it is not both permitted and inheritable.

          The ambient capability set can be directly modified using
          prctl(2).  Ambient capabilities are automatically lowered if
          either of the corresponding permitted or inheritable
          capabilities is lowered.

          Executing a program that changes UID or GID due to the set-
          user-ID or set-group-ID bits or executing a program that has
          any file capabilities set will clear the ambient set.  Ambient
          capabilities are added to the permitted set and assigned to
          the effective set when execve(2) is called.

   A child created via fork(2) inherits copies of its parent's
   capability sets.  See below for a discussion of the treatment of
   capabilities during execve(2).
```

…

```
       P'(ambient) = (file is privileged) ? 0 : P(ambient)

       P'(permitted) = (P(inheritable) & F(inheritable)) |
                       (F(permitted) & cap_bset) | P'(ambient)

       P'(effective) = F(effective) ? P'(permitted) : P'(ambient)

       P'(inheritable) = P(inheritable)    [i.e., unchanged]

   where:

       P         denotes the value of a thread capability set before the
                 execve(2)

       P'        denotes the value of a thread capability set after the
                 execve(2)

       F         denotes a file capability set

       cap_bset  is the value of the capability bounding set (described
                 below).
```

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to have a wrapper program that can execute **any** program with specific capabilities, **without having to set capabilities on target programs**. Such a wrapper is particularly useful to run software from a build directory (where `setcap` would be cumbersome) or to run interpreters like Python (where it would be inappropriate).

As explained in other answers, ambient capabilities solve this, but they are only available since kernel 4.3. It is possible to work around this problem by having the wrapper load the target program directly instead of using `exec`. By that, I mean open the executable, map relevant sections, set up the stack, etc., and jump to its code. This is a pretty complicated task, but luckily the **wine-preloader** program from the Wine project does exactly that (and some other things that are irrelevant for this purpose).

Run something like this as root to set up the wrapper:

```
cp /usr/bin/wine-preloader /path/to/wrapper
setcap cap_net_raw+ep /path/to/wrapper # set whatever capabilities you need
```

Now we have a copy of `wine-preloader` that is able to run any program with those capabilities:

```
/path/to/wrapper /path/to/executable arguments...
```

This works but there are some pitfalls:

- The target program must be a path to an executable, it cannot find programs in `PATH`.
- It does not work if the target program is a script with an interpreter (`#!`).
- The `wine-preloader` prints a message about not being able to find something (but it still runs the program fine).